# How can I load a map in XML format?

Tags: javascript, html

I used the Tiled map editor to make a XML file which has items listed as:

```
<data>
  <tile gid="1"/>
  <tile gid="2"/>
  <tile gid="2"/>
  <tile gid="1"/>
  <tile gid="1"/>
  <tile gid="3"/>
  <tile gid="3"/>
  <tile gid="1"/>
  <tile gid="2"/>
</data>
```

Say this was a 3x3 map. How can I parse this into an array as

```
[
  [1,2,2],
  [1,1,3],
  [3,1,2],
]
```

to load it easier? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to convert it to an array with this simple script:

```
var xml = '<data><tile gid="1"/><tile gid="2"/> <tile gid="2"/><tile gid="1"/><tile gid="1"/><tile gid="3"/><tile gid="3"/><tile gid="1"/><tile gid="2"/></data>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​';

​var data = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml").documentElement;

var tileNodes = data.querySelectorAll("tile");
var tiles = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tileNodes.length; i++) {
    var point = [];
    point.push(parseInt(tileNodes[i].getAttribute("gid"), 10));
    point.push(parseInt(tileNodes[++i].getAttribute("gid"), 10));
    point.push(parseInt(tileNodes[++i].getAttribute("gid"), 10));
    tiles.push(point);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to parseFromFile and not from string? I mean if the file is very long the string will be huge, no?

Comment: Directly from file no. But you can request the file from the server with ajax, and then you can parse the string that will be returned. There is no problem if the string is huge. It will work